# Error while installing package in CQ which contains users and groups

Tags: package, aem

I am trying to install a package on CQ instance which contains users and groups. The path for which package was created is for `/home` excluding `admin` user.

Please note that some users are already available on targeted CQ instance which might are also available in package.

Following exception was encountered, any help/views:

```
com.day.jcr.vault.packaging.PackageException: javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: /home/users/c/chris/.tokens/2014-10-16T12.45.01.614+02.00: mandatory property {internal}token.key does not exist
        at com.day.jcr.vault.packaging.impl.ZipVaultPackage.extract(ZipVaultPackage.java:365)
        at com.day.jcr.vault.packaging.impl.JcrPackageImpl.extract(JcrPackageImpl.java:368)
        at com.day.jcr.vault.packaging.impl.JcrPackageImpl.install(JcrPackageImpl.java:336)
        at com.day.crx.packaging.impl.J2EEPackageManager.consoleInstall(J2EEPackageManager.java:327)
        at com.day.crx.packaging.impl.J2EEPackageManager.doPost(J2EEPackageManager.java:173)
        at com.day.crx.packaging.impl.PackageManagerServlet.doPost(PackageManagerServlet.java:144)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:96)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:79)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:42)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:49)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
        at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:127)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
        at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
        at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:263)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
        at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:179)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:48)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:39)
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.service(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:250)
        at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.doFilter(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:321)
        at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:340)
        at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:383)
        at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletHandlerImpl.process(ServletHandlerImpl.java:335)
        at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:644)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Are you uploading and installing package with administrator privileges ? Would suggest to build a package from your target instance of users download it and then compare the .content.xml's with the ones you are trying to install.

Comment: Yes, I am logged in as admin while uploading/installing the package. And as for comparison, what should I look for while comparing `.content.xml`

Comment: You may compare the existing working users of the target CQ instance and the ones which you are trying to install ( by comparing their content.xml). The exception trace says the property is missing "mandatory property {internal}token.key does not exist" so do check that if this property is missing in the packages you are trying to install. Also CQ keeps some of the properties as protected and auto created so this may also be a reason for exception. Sorry I do not have to the point answer but only suggestions for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the `.tokens` nodes should be excluded when copying users and groups via content packages. Adding an exclude pattern like `<exclude pattern="/home/users/.*/.tokens"/>` when creating the package should help.

Comment: how does it "not work"? Are the .tokens nodes correctly removed from the content package (unzip + look at relevant .content.xml files will tell you) or are they removed but the package install still fails?

Comment: I guess as this is a regex it should be: "<exclude pattern="/home/users/.*/\.tokens"/>" The "dot" needs to be escaped

Answer (score 0):

While creating a package using crx/packmgr use `/home/users/username/\.tokens` as pattern.

Answer (score -1):

The way i resolve this is I download the package in my local. Find all those users inside the package with existing tokens inside .content.xml and remove them.