# CQ | migrate users from one CQ instance to another

Tags: migration, package, aem

When migrating/copying users/groups from one cq instance to another cq instance, what is the best approach. I have looked almost everywhere and found only [1]. But going by mentioned approach it throws exception (details are mentioned [2]).

Please note all the users/groups are cq users/groups and there is no LDAP. Some users which needs to be migrated from old cq instance to new already exists on new cq instance as well and working as well.

[1] http://www.hsufengko.com/home/copy-users-groups-permissions-acls-between-adobe-cq-instances

[2] [Error while installing package in CQ which contains users and groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778346/error-while-installing-package-in-cq-which-contains-users-and-groups)

Any help/suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add acs-commons package in your aem instance first, then you have a tool in the http://localhost:4502/miscadmin to create a acl package for you.

Just go to "http://localhost:4502/miscadmin#/etc/acs-commons/packagers" and create a new page using the ACL Packager template. Here you can include the number you patterns for your users. This will help you to build the users package for copying into multiple instances.